# PHP with azure database

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to make connection between azure database and php. I come to know that i need to install sqlsrv driver on server.

Is it possible to install sqlsrv driver on linux/ubuntu.Please give your support.

Is there any alternate method to make connection between azure db and php on linux.?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

a great [article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/windows-azure-php#fig_iaaspaas) :

> he SQL Server Driver for PHP allows
>   PHP developers to access SQL Server
>   databases that are hosted on SQL
>   Server or SQL Azure. The SQL Server
>   Driver for PHP relies on the Microsoft
>   SQL Server ODBC Driver to handle
>   low-level communication with SQL
>   Server. **As a result, the SQL Server
>   Driver for PHP is only supported on
>   Windows and Windows Azure.** It can be
>   [downloaded](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/) and installed as a PHP
>   extension

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use OData to access your SQL Azure (or Azure Table Storage) data from PHP.  Not sure what the perf differences would be, but you'd be able to avoid installing the database driver on your LAMP box.

http://odataphp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I was really excited when I found this unfortunately Microsoft has seemed to have stoped odata access to azure for now http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazurelabs/labs/odata.aspx